# Dynamic height of usercontrol depending on content of textblock

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I am trying to create a control with a dynamic height which is based on the content of the included textblock.
Here is my code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Test.UI.View.Controls.ErrorBannerControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test.UI.View.Controls"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="400"
         MinHeight="40" MaxHeight="64"
         Background="#FFF8F8">
<Grid Margin="16,8,16,8">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="16"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Text="&#xE783;" 
               FontSize="16" Foreground="Red" 
               VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlockError" Margin="8,0,0,0" Foreground="Red" FontSize="12"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace Test.UI.View.Controls
{
/// <summary>
///     Interaktionslogik für ErrorBannerControl.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class ErrorBannerControl : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ErrorTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ErrorText", typeof(string), typeof(ErrorBannerControl),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(ErrorTextChangedCallback));

    public ErrorBannerControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string ErrorText
    {
        get => (string) GetValue(ErrorTextProperty);
        set => TextBlockError.Text = value;
    }

    private static void ErrorTextChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var errorBannerControl = (ErrorBannerControl) d;
        errorBannerControl.TextBlockError.Text = Convert.ToString(e.NewValue);
    }
}
```

The min height of the control should be 40px. This height is used for a message which contains only one line of text.
If the text wraps the control should change it height to 52px to show the second line.
Wrapping the text again to a third line the control should grow to 64px.
Every text which get longer than three lines should be shown with a scrollbar.

My problem is that the control's height is 64px from the beginning and i have no idea how i can a achieve my expected beavior. Have i do it programmatically in the code behind file?

Comment: The source of the "problem" is certainly the layout performed by the UserControl's parent element. Put it in a StackPanel or set its VerticalAlignment to Top.

Comment: @ActionHeinz: How is the `UserControl` used? Where is it inserted into the visual tree?

Comment: In my test the control is on a stackpanel in a grid:

    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <test:ErrorBanner Background="AntiqueWhite"
                                  ErrorText="vxcvxcvxcvxcvvxcvxcvxfsdfsdfsdffsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfdsfsdfsdfdsfsdfc"></test:ErrorBanner>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>